# How to find all enum fields in a class in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Today, we are able to get fields type for a lambda class by doing : `User.columns.map { |c| [c.name, c.type]}`

If a field is an enum, it will return the type `integer`. Is there anyway to find which fields are set as an enum from an active record class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get it as (provided by `ActiveRecord::Enum`),

```
User.defined_enums.keys
```

Answer (score 0):

```
User.columns.map { |c| [c.name, c.type, User.defined_enums[c.name]].compact }
```